# ssh connection spits out sql client connection logging, how do i stop this?

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm Running Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on google cloud compute engine. this server hosts a website which in turn uses the sql client to connect to a sql instance also running on google cloud platform. I connect to the webserver using ssh which all is fine until I connect to the sql instance.

once this connection is made and the website also can connect to the database my screen is flooded with messages like:

> 2017/07/12 16:56:30 New connection for
>   "snappy-gantry-xxxxxx:europe-west1:xxxxx" 2017/07/12 16:56:30 Client
>   closed local connection on
>   /cloudsql/snappy-gantry-xxxxxx:europe-west1:xxxxx

This makes it undo-able for me to continue working on this machine. How can i disable this so i can continue my work?

As it is the server is still in development. when it goes to production is don't mind it but even then i don't need those messages.

Comment: Try `sudo dmesg -n 1`.

Comment: Still gives the same messages

Comment: Thank you again @jww i guess... I've looked at the topics about questions to ask here and in my opinion i am at the right plate. one of the bullet points state: "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is". My question concerns the mysql client which is common enough if you ask me. Although you can debate if it is a 'software tool' it is a tool commonly used.

Answer (score -1):

The problem doesnt occur anymore. What i first did was setting up the connection with sql under my own user account which then spit out the logging. I now started it under the service account and when i log in under my own name i don't see the logging anymore.